# Range.DisplayFormat method and VBA Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if there are any duplicates in my column, I set a conditional formatting manually and then I made the following test :

```
            If cell2.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 199, 206) Then

                Label8.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 2).Text
                Label9.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 3).Text
                Label10.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 4).Text
                Label12.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 5).Text
                Label13.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 6).Text
                Label28.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 7).Text
                Label30.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 8).Text
                CommandButton2.Enabled = True

            Else
                cell2.Value = ""
                MsgBox "Votre bac existe déjà", vbExclamation, "Bac double"
                Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
                Me.TextBox1.SetFocus

            End If
```

The problem is that I use Excel 2007, and this one does not support `Range.DisplayFormat` method, so what I need is one of the following :

- An alternative to `Range.DisplayFormat` method.
  OR
- Another way to test the duplicates without using conditional formatting.

THANK YOU!

Comment: any reason why you can't use the inbuilt highlight duplicates functionality of conditional formatting in the gome tab?

Comment: I'm using it, my code can't run without conditional formatting. The problem is that checking with `Range.DisplayFormat` method  is not available for Excel  2007.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt conditional formatting functionality

Either

1) select the area to highlight and then go to `Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight cell rules > Duplicate Values` and choose your format

Or

2) Use code similar to the following:

```
Sub findDupsInMyCol()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row number
    Set rngSelection = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 'set target range
    ws.Activate
    FormatDups rngSelection 

End Sub


Sub FormatDups(ByRef rngSelected As Range)

    rngSelected.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    rngSelected.FormatConditions(rngSelected.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rngSelected.FormatConditions(1)
        .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        .Font.Color = -16383844
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.Color = 13551615
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it's really valuable but what I want is just a function that does a boolean check (returning True or False)  and having for entry the Range and the value.

Comment: Where would it return this information? Presumably, depending on how you apply the conditional formatting, you could check for the .FormatConditions(1).Interior properties (e.g. as set by using the 2007 highlight duplicates functionality). Sort of a reversal of my code, where rather than setting, test for those settings (having applied them manually). You could loop a range doing this test and store the ranges found and their values in dictionary.